# How to send ExpectedConditions to a function?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to write a generic function that gets `ExpectedConditions` and `Locator`:

```
public WebElement findElementElements(ExpectedConditions expectedConditions, By locator){
    WebDriver driver...
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait...

    return driver.webDriverWait().until(expectedConditions(locator));
}
```

But I get this compiler error: "Method call expected"

Comment: What do you intend `expectedConditions(locator)` to do? You're not specifying which method to call.

Comment: Also, at least show the real full code and the full error message. It is hard to debug your issue or guess what you intended to do without seeing your actual code.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I guess he is asking about the generic method that will receive `expectedConditions` and `locator` parameters and return the element located by the passed `locator` and fulfilling the desired `expectedConditions` condition like visibility, clickability etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all `ExpectedCondtions` return the same type... some return `WebElement`, others return `Boolean`. This method expects `ExpectedConditions` that return `WebElement`s.

```
public WebElement findElement(Function<WebDriver, WebElement> expectedCondition) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expectedCondition);
}
```

and you can call it like

```
WebElement e = findElement(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("myId")));
```

NOTE: You don't need the `locator` parameter because that's a required part of the `ExpectedCondition`.